# How to retrieve database information from a desktop application?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a desktop application which is developed in Java, The application is having a built in MS SQL Server. I forgot the database details. Now I want to retrieve the database and the table structures. Is there any way to retrieve the information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step #1) Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To get all tables and columns

```
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

or

To get all tables

```
Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I've one more doubt, I don't have access to the database. I mean username & password. Can I know where the database is stored locally? Can I access the database even though I don't have authentication?

Comment: @e-Designers without the proper authentication, I can't imagine how you would retrieve the database info.

Comment: That is my problem. I don't have authentication. How can I access it now?

Comment: @e-Designers Again, without the proper credentials, you can't (this is a good thing).  If you are not the author of the desktop application, you will have to contact your DBA or System Administrator.

Comment: Thank You :), the application is designed by some other person but I don't know where he is now. So I asked for the help, is there any way to retrieve?